# Java: How to select/call a function by a strings content?

Tags: java, reflection

I have a list and I have functions.

I want to iterate the list and call the function that matches the lists element.
How can I do that in a more elegant way than comparing the name in a if or switch?

```
class C
{
  String [] lst = {"foo", "bar", "zoo"};

  void foo () { /* ... */ }
  void bar () { /* ... */ }

  void NotSoElegant ()
  {
    for (String s : lst)
    {
      if (s.equals ("foo") == true)
      { foo (); }
      if (s.equals ("bar") == true)
      { bar (); }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You can have a look at this (Possible duplicate): [How do I invoke a Java method when given the method name as a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160970/how-do-i-invoke-a-java-method-when-given-the-method-name-as-a-string)

Comment: You could create a `Map<String, Runnable>` or `Map<String, Consumer<C>>` to avoid your if branches.

Comment: @maloomeister For a case like this, that answer was made obsolete by Java 8.

Answer (score 5):

I strongly advise against to use reflection in such case - it's obviously code smell, it's breaching the security of your code and may cause many, many issues and drawbacks - just think what will happen if someone will put `NotSoElegant` in the list.

Of course there are [methods to fetch method by name](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/classMembers.html) so basically you could scan the class, get method by string, handle exceptions... Do not do this.

Basically there is nothing bad in having such set of `ifs` however you can refactor this a little bit using `switch` statement

```
for (String s : lst) {
    switch(s) {
        case "foo": 
            foo();
            break;
        case "bar": 
            bar();
            break;
    }
}
```

If you want to be more SOLID complain and do not break *Open-Closed* rule you should rather think about using some design patterns (like [Strategy](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/strategy)) but do not use reflection :)

Comment: Arrow-cases would make the code even better to read.

Answer (score 3):

Use the *Replace Conditional with Polymorphism* refactoring along with lambdas/method references. Assuming that your methods don't take parameters and don't return anything, they match the `Runnable` interface:

```java
class MoreElegant {

  static final Map<String, Runnable> COMMANDS = Map.of(
    "foo", MoreElegant::foo,
    "bar", MoreElegant::bar,
    "baz", () -> { doSomethingElse(); }
  );

  void execute(List<String> commands) {
    commands.forEach(c ->
      COMMANDS
        .getOrDefault(c, () -> throw new IllegalArgumentException("no command " + c))
        .run()
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: "Assuming that your methods don't take parameters and don't return anything" — and are static, since you're putting them in a static field.

Comment: @khelwood The approach generalizes simply enough.